# Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null. Alguien sabe por qué me sale ese error si estoy declarando el id del DIV?

Tags: javascript, html5

alguien podría resolverme esa duda? estoy tratando de imprimir un div en pdf pero cuando doy click al botón de pdf me aparece este error en consola. Ya intenté resolverlo pero simplemente no encuentro solución. Es para entregar un trabajo y me urge que ya quede. Si alguien sabe cual es mi error, me gustaría que me lo hicieran saber. Este es mi fragmento de código, cabe aclarar que no es mi código, sólo me lo dieron para que hiciera esa mejora pero hay muchas cosas que no entiendo

```js
                interface += '<div  onclick="ocultarUIComentario('+id+','+id_grupo+')" style="cursor: pointer;color: rgb(26, 56, 56);background-color: rgb(238, 224, 227);z-index: 9999999999999;" class="jb_x_publicacion">x</div><button type="button" style="cursor: pointer;color: rgb(26, 56, 56);background-color: rgb(216, 29, 29); color:white; width: 38px; height: 21px; font-size: 10px;  z-index: 9999999999999;" onclick="printDiv(\''+contenido_publicacion+'\')" value="imprimir div">PDF</button><span style="display:none" id="jb_id_grupopub_'+id+'">'+id_grupo+'</span><span style="display:none" id="jb_id_grupopub_micro'+id+'">'+id_grupo+'</span>';
                

function printDiv(contenido_publicacion) {
var contenido= document.getElementById("contenido_publicacion").innerHTML;
var contenidoOriginal= document.body.innerHTML;

document.body.innerHTML = contenido;

window.print();

document.body.innerHTML = contenidoOriginal;
}
```

Comment: el id si es `contenido_publicacion`? sólo sería que te cerciores de eso. si es el div que creas en interface, no tiene ID.

Comment: Sercioarte de que primero se cargue la pagina antes de ejecutar el script, de lo contrario todos los `document.get` que hagas siempre seran null o undefined.

Comment: @L.Ronquillo lo estoy llamando por su clase y ya revisé que es la correcta

Comment: @Riven si, se carga bien, no entiendo por qué sale ese error

Comment: Es mas facil solucionar el error si nos muestras el `HTML` que tienes como tal, porfavor edita la pregunta y pon el `HTML`, nos serviria de mucho.

Comment: @Riven es que no tiene un archivo html como tal, todo está maquetado con js

Comment: @UlisesMontoya Exacto, ese es el problema, `document.getElementById` toma los elementos por el documento, si el documento no contiene dicho elemento no vas a poder obtenerlo, si lo que me tratas de decir es que no usas `html` en lo absoluto y todo lo añades desde `javascript`, la verdad no es muy buena idea, pero si lo haces de esa manera debes considerar que entonces deberas tratar de obtener los elementos con `document.get...` despues de que los hayas introducido a la pagina, de lo contrario no existiran, ademas la ultima linea del codigo que mostraste reinicia todo.